# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'France'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Error while using oneHotEncoder in Python.

I was learning Machine Learning using Python following Udemy course. When I tried to use oneHotEncorder for encoding country names in the source data, i get the below error.

```
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'France'
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
oneHotEncObj=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
X=oneHotEncObj.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

Try replace the onehotencoder with `preprocessing.LabelEncoder()`

Comment: Yep, from `OneHotEncoder` documentation: "Encode categorical __integer__ features as a one-hot numeric array."

Comment: Got a little confused, If I use LabelEncoder, i will replace one string with one digit right? But I need to encode each label using morethan one digits as in the second screenshot I have added

Answer (score 0):

fit_transform  method of LabelEncoder, Fits label encoder and return encoded labels

hence you need to assign the return value of labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0]) to X[:,0]

The complete code will be

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:,0]= labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0])
oneHotEncoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features =[0])
X=oneHotEncoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```